# Client-Server in c#

Tags: c#, client, client-server

I'm looking for a tutorial/example for writing a client application and a server application.
I wish to send the server commands to run, and have the server run them.

Comment: Yes, I did, doesn't work...

Comment: 0 research, 0 effort, and this is not even a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) (server) and [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) (client) on MSDN, examples included.

As for sending commands, you can simple send strings and parse them at the other end. But if you want to go a step further, look up the Command design pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Google it with keyword : example client server C#

Try this :

1. [Introduction to TCP client server in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C)
2. [Simple-Client-server-Interactions-using-C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12286/Simple-Client-server-Interactions-using-C)