# Simple Client-server Interactions using C#

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, client

I try to create Cliect - Server and fount this post: 
[Client-Server in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545877/client-server-in-c-sharp)
who lead me to this page: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C

At the beginning i found the link Socket.zip that is CS file, my question is what to do with this file ? (i am a new developer...)

Comment: You'll need to compile it and then run the `.exe`.  If you've never compiled an application before, a TCP client/server application may be too advanced. Start small: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: When i am open this file i cannot compile it, maybe i need to copy all the classes to another project ? (i know how to compile...)

Comment: Look at this file, maybe i need to import this file ?